# Echo string to .txt file with multiple lines - with Windows Batch file

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I am attempting to create a Windows Batch File that creates a .txt with mulitple lines. I've tried several solutions to insert a line break in the string but no avail. There are other similar questions/answers but none of them address putting the entire string into a text file.

My batch file currently reads:

```
echo Here is my first line
Here is my second line > myNewTextFile.txt
pause
```

my goal is to have the text file read:

```
Here is my first line
Here is my second line
```

Obviously, this does not work currently, but wondering if anyone knows how to make this happen in a simple fashion?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

```
(
echo Here is my first line
echo Here is my second line
echo Here is my third line
)>"myNewTextFile.txt"
pause
```

Comment: This did the job excellently, tho for future reference the "quotation" marks around the file name ended up not being necessary.

Comment: The quotes aren't necessary but are good practice, for when `&` or space characters are in the filename or full path. You will also find that closing brackets need to be escaped as in `^)` when using this solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, when brackets '(' are in the text to be echoed. The solution with > and >> still works.

Comment: For the sake of clarity in conversation and eliminating the need to type "(", "[", "{"... The proper terms for these characters are:
Parentheses: ()
Brackets, or Square Brackets:[]
Braces, or Curly Braces: {}

Comment: @Bob Brackets is a general term for all of those marks (including parentheses, which can certainly be called "round brackets"). Using "brackets" without qualification to mean square brackets [] specifically is only common in the US (and not even universal there), while in the British English it would mean round brackets (). This makes more sense any IMO since outside of computing the most commonly used brackets are round by an enormous margin. In any case, it certainly makes sense to just type out the type (square, round, curly) and type them out explicitly rather than risk confusion.

Comment: @michael_s The solution to this is in the comment right above yours: escape any round brackets with a caret `^`

Comment: This process will add output of each echo command to the target file. 
Is there a way to put block of lines without adding echo statement infront of each line and with out redirect at end of each line.

Comment: This also works for piping to a command, in which case `>>` solutions does not work unless you want to create a temporary file, for example to  automate `diskpart`

Comment: Is the `pause` command at the end required or is it just added because the OP has it in his script?

Comment: Is not working for echo comments like #  for me on ubuntu 18

Comment: @user224767 this is a Batch script for Windows, not bash for Linux :)

Answer (score 39):

Just repeat the `echo` and `>>` for lines after the first.  `>>` means that it should append to a file instead of creating a new file (or overwriting an existing file):

```
echo Here is my first line > myNewTextFile.txt
echo Here is my second line >> myNewTextFile.txt
echo Here is my third line >> myNewTextFile.txt
pause
```

Comment: Is the `pause` command at the end required or is it just added because the OP has it in his script?

Comment: @AdityaVikasDevarapalli: It's just there because it was in the poster's code. It is not required or necessary.

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me while this one did.

Comment: Note that this will write spaces at the end of lines, because there is a space between the last word and `>`. Not normally a problem, but a hard one with some machine-readable files. Remove the spaces from the source code to fix.

Answer (score 11):

Searching for something else, I stumbled on this meanwhile old question, and I have an additional little trick that is worth mentioning, I think.

All solutions have a problem with empty lines and when a line starts with an option for the echo command itself. Compare the output files in these examples:

```
call :data1 >file1.txt
call :data2 >file2.txt
exit /b

:data1
echo Next line is empty
echo
echo /? this line starts with /?
echo Last line
exit /b

:data2
echo:Next line is empty
echo:
echo:/? this line starts with /?
echo:Last line
exit /b
```

Now, file1.txt contains:

```
Next line is empty 
ECHO is off. 
Displays messages, or turns command-echoing on or off.

  ECHO [ON | OFF]
  ECHO [message]

Type ECHO without parameters to display the current echo setting. 
Last line
```

While file2.txt contains:

```
Next line is empty

/? this line starts with /?
Last line
```

The use of `echo:` miraculously solves the issues with the output in file1.txt.

Besides the colon, there are other characters that you could 'paste' to `echo`, among them a dot, a slash, ... Try for yourself.

Comment: Nice to know that colon works as well, I thought the documented version was dot as in `echo.` and `echo./? whatever`

Answer (score 2):

STEP 1: Enter Line 1 followed by the ^ character.

```
echo Here is my first line^
```

STEP 2: Hit RETURN key to get a prompt for more text

```
echo Here is my first line^ 
More?
```

STEP 3: Hit RETURN key once more to get a second prompt for more text

```
echo Here is my first line^ 
More?
More?
```

STEP 4: Continue line 2 from the second prompt

```
echo Here is my first line^ 
More?
More? Here is my second line
```

STEP 5: Hit the RETURN key to get 2 statements displayed on two separate lines

Results:

```
echo Here is my first line^ 
More?
More? Here is my second line
Here is my first line  
Here is my second line
```

**NOTE**
However, if you wish to save this to file, you could add a final STEP.
STEP 6: with the help of the > character, you can append the filename so you save your output to file instead.

```
echo Here is my first line^ 
More?
More? Here is my second line >"myNewTextFile.txt"
```

[Example from CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cM5I.png)

Comment: this solution only works in command prompt, not in a batch files.