# How do I make a batch file create another one with code in it

Tags: batch-file

I made this batch file and then I wanted to make an installer for that with batch but then I got stuck on the making the batch file with code part.

I tried using this:

```
cat > %drev%:\Notekeeper\Program.bat << EOF
script script script
script script script
EOF
```

but then I realized I needed to add echo before every line. And that is a problem when you have 300+ lines of code...

So, is there a easier way to do it where I don't have to add `echo` before everything?

Comment: This looks like a shell script not a batch file.

Comment: Yeah, between the use of `cat` and the heredoc, I'd wager this is actually bash. Or are you trying to port a bash script to batch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get the number of the "<resource>" line
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "<resource>" "%~F0"') do set "start=%%a"

rem Skip such number of lines and show the rest of this file
(for /F "usebackq skip=%start% delims=" %%a in ("%~F0") do echo %%a) > Program.bat

goto :EOF

<resource>
script script script
script script script
```

There are several modifications that can be done on this code, for example:

- Place the section of code at other place (not at end of this file).
- More than one section of code.
- Expand some %variables% when the code is being copied.
- Et cetera...

Note: the inclusion of code in other types of files is managed in a section called `<resource>`, so I just used the same term.

Comment: Thanks helped alot

Comment: I've been searching this script for months... Nice script!

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
scriptA
scriptB
)2>>fileA.txt:stream1

for /f %%p in (fileA.txt:stream1) do (
    set a=%%p
    set a=!a:'=!
        echo !a!>> fileA.txt
)
```

The script above will do:

- Redirect `scriptA`..... into `fileA.txt`'s stream1 (you can't see that)
- As `fileA.txt`'s stream1 will be filled with:

  > 'scriptA' is not a regonized.....
- The `for` loop will remove the unneeded text and redirect them into 
  the correct `fileA.txt`

Here's another way, but it only shortens the `>>"file.txt"`, not the `echo`

```
(
echo script
echo script
echo script
)>>"file.txt"
```

Taken from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530496/echo-string-to-txt-file-with-multiple-lines-with-windows-batch-file#answers)

**Edit:**

As @Aacini commented, special characters will need to be escaped.

Comment: In this solution all special characters (like `>`, `|`, `)`, etc) must be escaped in the "script" code. In the first method the script code can not include any wild-char, like in `dir *.txt`.

Comment: the wildcard problem is fixed