# GitHub Auto version in file after commit

Tags: git, github

I need write and update version nubmer in file "Plugin.cs" on github after every commit
How to do that ?

Plugin.cs have line:

```
public Version Version => new Version(2, 2, 111);
```

What i need to do to autochange 111 to **112** after commit or merge pull request ?

Thanks advance

Comment: Have you done any research or attempted anything yourself? I refuse to believe that no  one has ever documented a solution to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed git commit hash in a .Net dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141338/embed-git-commit-hash-in-a-net-dll)