# FileVersionInfo.ProductVersion suddenly contains git commit hash

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, .net-8.0

I have a .NET 6 WPF project and cannot figure out what changed as the `ProductVersion` of my assembly suddenly contains a git commit hash.

My project file always looked like this, where I also updated the version information:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    ...
    <Version>0.9.2</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then, in my code I use the following to get the version as string:

```
 string? productVersion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()!.Location).ProductVersion;
```

This always returned the version as expected, e.g. `0.9.2`, exactly as it was set in the project file. But something changed and now it looks like this: `0.9.2+abf5b643b64475a8b1d7d89284e3478b1ba4a431`. This is also what shows up in Explorer on the Details tabs of the .dll and .exe files.

I do regularly update Visual Studio in order to receive updates on .NET 8 which I use in other projects, so it may be related to some update. But I've no idea what exactly changed or how I can define the `ProductVersion` to not include the git commit hash (and yes, it's the commit hash). Haven't worked on the WPF project for a while as well, so don't know when this behavior changed.

Ironically, I needed the git commit in the past so had to put in some [extra effort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71747677/1649108) to have this available, though abbreviated to 8 characters.

Any ideas?

Comment: The value can be overridden by the AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute.

Comment: @shingo thank you! Indeed, looking at the `obj`  folder, I see a basic `<project>.AssemblyInfo.cs` with the `AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute` as it is intended by me, but also a `<project>_<tmpchars>.AssemblyInfo.cs` with the modified `AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute`. So I guess something in the build process is adding it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The described behavior can be disabled by adding

```xml
<IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>false</IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>
```

to the project file.

It seems to be introduced by SourceLink related changes in the SDK 8 version. I found an existing github issue as well:
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/34568

Comment: Alternatively you can try using `global.json` to build with .NET 6 SDK.

Comment: i wish they had made "false" the default :-(

Comment: Please note that this line specifically needs to be inside the <PropertyGroup></PropertyGroup> node of the project file. If you simply "add it to the project file" as I first did, the project will fail to load due to being invalid.

Comment: M$FT, if you are out there, turning this on by default really sucks. Cost me a whole day of troubleshooting :(