# Problems when getting ProductVrsion for running program

Tags: c#

I am using the following code to get version information, but got very strange result.

`var version = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).ProductVersion;`

The output for this code is normal in my test project. Like `1.0.0.0`.

However, in working project, the output is like `1.0.0+b3ceb941668d15eeb55eac1d384725acb00967f7`. It seems to have a GUID string as suffix, but I didn't set this suffix anywhere.

I also found that this suffix varies when I change the machine to build it, but it keeps the same on each machine.

Does anyone know how this suffix come and how to set it?

Comment: That looks like the SHA-1 of your git repo.

Comment: @shingo You are right! This suffix is the id of my working branch. So, the output for my test project looks normal is because it is no in a git repo?

Comment: Yes. And I have seen a similar question before, I remember it should be configurable.

Comment: Here it is: [FileVersionInfo.ProductVersion suddenly contains git commit hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77050814/fileversioninfo-productversion-suddenly-contains-git-commit-hash)